# RigidBody2D projectile to target calculation

Tags: vector, unity-game-engine, projectile

I am using this code to shoot a projectile in order to hit a target on the ground.

I am applying an impulse force in the x direction, which is calculated from its height above the target. I am working out the force to add by dividing the x distance by the time it will take to fall due to gravity, but this does not seem to work:

```c#
float xDist = flag.position.x - transform.position.x;
float yDist = transform.position.y - flag.position.y;
float smallY = (4/9.81f) + (0.5f*-9.81f*Mathf.Pow((4/9.81f), 2));

yDist = yDist + smallY;

float yImpactForce = Mathf.Sqrt(2*9.81f*yDist);
float xForce = xDist/(Mathf.Sqrt(2*yDist/9.81f));
```

Can anyone help me?

Not sure if my calculations are wrong, or whether the physics is rather different than a real life situation. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks

EDITS: The `smallY` variable is used to find the distance to the peak of the projectile's trajectory

Comment: Force is acceleration. You cant divide the total distance by time to get acceleration, they aren't linearly correlated (what you get is a constant *velocity*).

Comment: @Draco18s But I am trying to work out the initial x velocity to get to the destination in the time it takes to naturally fall due to gravity. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

From memory

dist = (a * t<sup>2</sup>)/2

so solving for time gives:

t = sqrt(2 * dist/a)

Therefore, your initial velocity calculation should be:

```
float fallTime = Mathf.Sqrt(2*yDist/9.81f);
float xVel = xDist/fallTime;
```

At least that's in the real world.

Since you are just trying to impact a specific velocity, it would be easier to just use `ForceMode.VelocityChange`.

To account for the y velocity in the updated version of the question, the additional time will be, assuming a positive (upwards) y-component (from v = a * t or t = v/a, times 2 -- once for decelerating to zero and once for accelerating back to the starting velocity and height, but in the other direction):

```
float fallTime = Mathf.Sqrt(2*yDist/9.81f);
var yTime = 2 * (yVel / 9.81f);
falltime += yTime;
float xVel = xDist/fallTime;
```

Comment: I probably should have asked this in the full question, do you know how I could use this with a Y force. I have updated the question with my full code. I am trying to calculate the x velocity when y velocity is known (4). When I add no Y velocity, this code works fine. But as soon as I add Y velocity it doesn't reach the target.

Comment: I think your answer should work, but for some reason it doesn't seem to. It doesn't correctly reach the x value needed. Thanks for all the help so far. If I can't solve this soon I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion. It's pretty basic physics. I derived my formulas from my distant memories of grade 10 physics, most (all?) of the formulas in that topic use the launch angle, which I think is what you are trying to derive, at least indirectly.